# Trie Tree match string containing ? and *

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, tree, trie

Using Python 2.7 and here is my code which implement trie match for a whole word, and also support if the whole word contains `?` (match any one character) or `*` (any zero or more characters).

My question is wondering if any improvement I can make (in terms of performance) and also if any code functional bugs, please feel free to point out.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.isEnd = False

    def insert(self, source):
        if not source:
            return
        node = self
        for s in source:
            node = node.children[s]
        node.isEnd = True

    def search(self, source):
        if not source:
            return self.isEnd == True
        if source[0] == '?':
            for (ch,node) in self.children.items():
                if node.search(source[1:]) == True:
                    return True
            return False
        elif source[0] == '*':
            for (ch, node) in self.children.items():
                if ((node.search(source[1:]) == True) or
                    (node.search(source) == True)):
                    return True
            return False
        else:
            if source[0] in self.children:
                node = self.children[source[0]]
                return node.search(source[1:])
            else:
                return False
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = TrieNode()
    root.insert('abc')
    root.insert('acd')
    root.insert('bcd')
    print root.search('acd') # True
    print root.search('acdd') # False
    print root.search('aaa') # False
    print root.search('a?d') # True
    print root.search('a*d') # True
    print root.search('ad*') # False
    print root.search('*c*') # True
    print root.search('*c?') # True
    print root.search('*a?') # False
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. The implementation with `defaultdict` is very elegant. I like it.
2. The code is not portable to Python 3 because of the use of the `print` statement. It would be easy to make it portable using [`from __future__ import print_function`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html).
3. Set-like data structures contain *elements*, so `element` would be a better variable name than `source`.
4. It's inconvenient to create a trie from some other data structure like a list of strings: you have to call the `insert` method for each element you want to add. It would be better if the constructor took an optional iterator and inserted all the elements, just like the constructors for other collections in Python.
5. Instead of `self.isEnd == True`, just write `self.isEnd`, and similarly for other comparisons against `True`.
6. The attributes `children` and `isEnd` are only intended for use by the `TrieNode` class itself. It's conventional to give such attributes names starting with `_`.
7. The code for `insert` starts like this:

   ```
   if not source:
       return
   ```

   which means that if you try to add the empty string to the trie, it apparently succeeds, but in fact the empty string was not added. This is misleading. If you really want to prevent the caller adding the empty string, then raise an exception:

   ```
   if not source:
       raise ValueError("empty string not supported")
   ```

   But this seems inconvenient to me, so instead I suggest removing these two lines and allowing the empty string as an element. But this reveals a problem with the `search` method:

   ```
   >>> root = TrieNode()
   >>> root.insert('')
   >>> root.search('*')
   False
   ```

   To fix this, revise the `search` method as follows:

   ```
   elif source[0] == '*':
       if node.search(source[1:]):
           return True
       for (ch, node) in self.children.items():
           if node.search(source) == True:
               return True
       return False
   ```

   (but see below for further improvements to this code).
8. In this code:

   ```
   for (ch,node) in self.children.items():
       if node.search(source[1:]) == True:
           return True
   return False
   ```

   you don't make any use of `ch`, so it would be simpler to write:

   ```
   for node in self.children.values():
       if node.search(source[1:]):
           return True
   return False
   ```

   which is the same as:

   ```
   return any(node.search(source[1:]) for node in self.children.values())
   ```
9. Instead of computing `source[1:]` on each iteration of the loop, compute it once and remember it in a local variable:

   ```
   rest = source[1:]
   return any(node.search(rest) for node in self.children.values())
   ```

   But better still, reorganize the search so that it remembers the current index into the search term, then you don't have to construct all these substrings. See below for how this might be implemented.
10. The interface to the `search` method makes it impossible to tell if strings containing wildcards are elements of the trie. Consider:

    ```
    >>> import random
    >>> root = TrieNode()
    >>> root.insert(random.choice(['?', 'x']))
    >>> root.search('?')
    True
    ```

    Is `'?'` a member of the trie or not? It would make sense to provide an alternative search method that doesn't use wildcards: for example the caller could write `'element' in trie` instead of `trie.search('element')`. This requires a `__contains__` method, which is straightforward to implement since it doesn't need to consider wildcards:

    ```
    def __contains__(self, element):
        node = self
        for k in element:
            if k not in node._children:
                return False
            node = node._children[k]
        return node._end
    ```

    Now you can accurately determine membership for strings containing wildcards:

    ```
    >>> '?' in root
    False
    ```
11. The `search` method only tells you whether *some* element in the trie matched the search term, and doesn't tell you which element or elements match. When the search term contains wildcards, it would be more useful if the search generated the matching elements. For example, if you have added the words in a dictionary to a trie, then you'd like to be able to query `'p?t'` and get out `'pat', 'pet', 'pit', 'pot', 'put'`. See the revised code in §2 below, and further discussion in §3.
12. The data structure presents a set-like interface (it represents a collection of distinct strings where you can add new elements and test elements for membership). It would therefore make sense to design the interface so that it uses the same method names as Python's built-in sets, that is, `add` instead of `insert`, and to implement more of the set interface, for example `__iter__`, `__len__`, `__or__`, `__and__` and so on.

    The easiest way to do this is to inherit from [`collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set). The idea is that your class implements the `__contains__`, `__iter__` and `__len__` methods, and `collections.abc.Set` class implements the other set methods in terms of these. See the revised code in §2 below.
13. The code has test cases, but it's hard to check that they are correct: you have to carefully compare the output against the expected output. It would be better to get the computer to do the work here, using the features in the [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module.

#### 2. Revised code

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import defaultdict
from collections.abc import Set

class TrieNode(Set):
    """A set of strings implemented using a trie."""

    def __init__(self, iterable=()):
        self._children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self._end = False
        for element in iterable:
            self.add(element)

    def add(self, element):
        node = self
        for s in element:
            node = node._children[s]
        node._end = True

    def __contains__(self, element):
        node = self
        for k in element:
            if k not in node._children:
                return False
            node = node._children[k]
        return node._end

    def search(self, term):
        """Return the elements of the set matching the search term, which may
        include wildcards ? (matching exactly one character) and *
        (matching zero or more characters).

        """
        results = set() # Set of elements matching search term.
        element = []    # Current element reached in search.
        def _search(m, node, i):
            # Having just matched m, search for term[i:] starting at node.
            element.append(m)
            if i == len(term):
                if node._end:
                    results.add(''.join(element))
            elif term[i] == '?':
                for k, child in node._children.items():
                    _search(k, child, i + 1)
            elif term[i] == '*':
                _search('', node, i + 1)
                for k, child in node._children.items():
                    _search(k, child, i)
            elif term[i] in node._children:
                _search(term[i], node._children[term[i]], i + 1)
            element.pop()
        _search('', self, 0)
        return results

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.search('*'))

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(1 for _ in self)
```

#### 3. Efficiency

1. The `Set` class requires implementations of `__iter__` and `__len__` so in the code above I implemented them as simply as possible to avoid making the answer too complicated. But if this is going to be used for anything serious then it would be a good idea to provide specialized implementations with better performance. The `__iter__` method could be implemented like this, using the [stack of iterators pattern](http://garethrees.org/2016/09/28/pattern/):

   ```
   def __iter__(self):
       element = ['']
       stack = [iter([('', self)])]
       while stack:
           for k, node in stack[-1]:
               element.append(k)
               if node._end:
                   yield ''.join(element)
               stack.append(iter(node._children.items()))
               break
           else:
               element.pop()
               stack.pop()
   ```

   And the `__len__` method can be made \$O(1)\$ if you maintained in each node a count of the number of elements in the trie rooted at that node:

   ```
   def __init__(self, iterable=()):
       self._children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
       self._end = False
       self._len = 0
       for element in iterable:
           self.add(element)

   def add(self, element):
       node = self
       for s in element:
           node = node._children[s]
       if not node._end:
           node._end = True 
           node._len += 1
           node = self
           for s in element:
               node._len += 1
               node = node._children[s]

   def __len__(self):
       return self._len
   ```
2. I made the `search` method return a set of elements matching the search term. It would be more general if this method *generated* the matching elements one at a time. This would more efficiently support use cases such as finding any element matching a search term (by stopping the iteration after the first result), or determining if there is a unique element matching a search term (by stopping the iteration after the second result).

   In Python 3 it's easy to implement this using the `yield from` statement, but in Python 2 you have to write:

   ```
   for result in _search(...):
       yield result
   ```

   which is rather verbose. But see below for an alternative.
3. The implementation of the `search` method is inefficient in the way it handles the `*` wildcard. The problem is that when the current character in the search term is `*`, the search descends the trie twice at each node (once having consumed the `*`, once not). This means that each node in the trie may be visited many times in the course of the search.

   It is possible to revise the code so that each node in the trie is visited at most once, by modifying the search method so that instead of considering a single index `i` in the search term, it considers a *set* of indexes.

   Here's one way to implement this, again using the [stack of iterators pattern](http://garethrees.org/2016/09/28/pattern/):

   ```
   def search(self, term):
       """Generate the elements of the set matching the search term, which
       may include wildcards.

       """
       def _add(indexes, i):
           # Add i to set of indexes into term, taking account of wildcards.
           while i < len(term) and term[i] == '*':
               indexes.add(i)
               i += 1
           indexes.add(i)

       indexes = set()
       _add(indexes, 0)
       if self._end and len(term) in indexes:
           yield ''

       indexes_stack = [indexes] # Stack of sets of indexes into term.
       element = ['']            # Current element reached in search.
       iter_stack = [iter(self._children.items())] # Stack of iterators.

       while iter_stack:
           for k, node in iter_stack[-1]:
               new_indexes = set()
               for i in indexes_stack[-1]:
                   if i >= len(term):
                       continue
                   elif term[i] == '*':
                       _add(new_indexes, i)
                   elif term[i] == '?' or term[i] == k:
                       _add(new_indexes, i + 1)
               if new_indexes:
                   element.append(k)
                   if node._end and len(term) in new_indexes:
                       yield ''.join(element)
                   indexes_stack.append(new_indexes)
                   iter_stack.append(iter(node._children.items()))
                   break
           else:
               element.pop()
               indexes_stack.pop()
               iter_stack.pop()
   ```

Comment: Learned a lot from you Gareth Rees! Mark your reply as answer and vote up!

Comment: Would have been useful to see the full version of your final solution. That way others could have tested it more easily.

Comment: @JGFMK: By all means suggest an edit.

Comment: I would suggest having either a single source file you could copy/paste. or a link to the full blown code somewhere like here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter - where you can run the code directly. It's too complicated to work out how to fit the pieces back together especially because of the versions..